# I am getting this watchdog Timer error while doing a simple task in arduino with esp32

Tags: arduino, watchdog, esp32

i have seen a lot of forums where this problem is dicussed but nothing seems to work. I am working with esp32 and it was all fine untill out of nowhere this watch dog timer error came up. I am new to it so i cant really fix this.
I have another code but i copied a very simple chunk of it and created a new file but watch dog timer error is appearing here too. I dont know what the issue.
it said idle0 is not resetting watach dog timer and "wifi" task is running on cpu0.

*ERROR LOG*
E (42418) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (42418) task_wdt:  - IDLE0 (CPU 0)
E (42418) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (42418) task_wdt: CPU 0: wifi
E (42418) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE1
E (42418) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400d96f7 on core 0

Backtrace: 0x4008c470:0x3ffbe270 0x4008c6a1:0x3ffbe290 0x400d96f7:0x3ffbe2b0 0x400815dd:0x3ffbe2d0 0x40136087:0x00000000

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1100
load:0x40078000,len:10088
load:0x40080400,len:6380
entry 0x400806a4

I have tried running my task on cpu1 or core 1 too but wifi is automatically running on cpu or core0. And getting the same error.
have also tried adding delays but nothing works.

````
char *wssid = "PTCL-TB";
char *wpassword = "pakistan";

bool connected2Wifi = false;
void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:

 Serial.begin(115200);
 delay(10);
 Serial.println('\n');

 WiFi.begin(wssid, wpassword);             // Connect to the network
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.print(wssid);

 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
   delay(500);
   Serial.print('.');
 }

 Serial.println('\n');
 Serial.println("Connection established!");  
 Serial.print("IP address:\t");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
}

void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

} ```

I want to connect to wifi in this task. It's very simple and i have also copied it from a reliable source whose code was running. but the error seems to be rigid.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools -> CPU Frequency and set it to 160, 80 or 240 MHz (the ones that support WiFi/BT).

Comment: You are a savior. Cheers! (Y)